# fabric different parameters in different hosts

Tags: python, fabric

Please tell me how can i execute fab-script in a list of hosts with the same command BUT with the different values of parameter.
Something like this:

```
from fabric.api import *

def command(parameter):
        run ("command%s" % parameter)
```

and execute this. I dont now how. For example:

**fab -H host1,host2,host3 command:param1 command:param2 command:param3**

And Fabric performs the following:

- command:param1 executed on host1
- command:param2 executed on host2
- command:param3 executed on host3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way I do this is to parametize the tasks. In my case it's about Deployment to Dev, Test and Production.

**fabfile.py:**

```
from ConfigParser import ConfigParser


from fabric.tasks import Task
from fabric.api import execute, task


@task()
def build(**options):
    """Your build function"""


class Deploy(Task):

    name = "dev"

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Deploy, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.options = kwargs.get("options", {})

    def run(self, **kwargs):
        options = self.options.copy()
        options.update(**kwargs)
        return execute(build, **options)


config = ConfigParser()
config.read("deploy.ini")

sections = [
    section
    for section in config.sections()
    if section != "globals" and ":" not in section
]

for section in sections:
    options = {"name": section}
    options.update(dict(config.items("globals")))
    options.update(dict(config.items(section)))

    t = Deploy(name=section, options=options)
    setattr(t, "__doc__", "Deploy {0:s} instance".format(section))
    globals()[section] = task
```

**deploy.ini:**

```
[globals]
repo = https://github.com/organization/repo

[dev]
dev = yes
host = 192.168.0.1
domain = app.local

[prod]
version = 1.0
host = 192.168.0.2
domain = app.mydomain.tld
```

Hopefully this is obvious enough to see that you can configure all kinds of deployments by simply editing your `deploy.ini` configuration file and subsequently automatically ceacreating new tasks that match with the right parameters.

This pattern can be adapted to [YAML](http://yaml.org/) or [JSON](http://json.org/) if that's your "cup of tea'>